# Key to Value to Key in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I feel this isn't the most elegant solution, but I'm looking for a way to to use values as keys in one and the same dictionary. The reasoning is that I can include multiple pieces of information in one place.

My current solution seems to work for only *one* of two dictionaries. I can't figure out why.

---

Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["BEAR ESTOX X12 S", "BEAR ESTOX X15 S", "BEAR AXP UN 3X VON", "BULL AXP UN x5 VON"], columns=["name"])
```

Two dictionaries:

```
sg = {"S":"SEG", "SG":"SEG", "SEG":"www.societegenerale.com"}
vontobel = {"VON":"Vontobel","Vontobel":"www.vontobel.com"}

issuer = sg.copy()
issuer.update(vontobel) #Combine both to one dictionary
```

I then do:

```
#Split last word in string to new column
df["issuer_spl"] = df.name.str.split().str.get(-1)

#Copy to column "issuer" and substitute abbreviations via dictionary
for i in issuer:
    df.loc[df.issuer_spl.str.contains(i), "issuer"] = issuer[i]

#Another pass in the dictionary, copying and substituting to column "website" 
for w in issuer:
    df.loc[df.issuer.str.contains(w).fillna(False), "website"] = issuer[w]
```

Produces output:

```
name                    issuer_spl      issuer          website
"BEAR ESTOX X12 S"      "S"             "SEG"           "SEG"
"BEAR ESTOX X15 S"      "S"             "SEG"           "SEG"
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"    "VON"           "Vontobel"      "www.vontobel.com"         
"BEAR AXP UN X3 VON"    "VON"           "Vontobel"      "www.vontobel.com"
```

What am I doing wrong that makes it key only the website for `"www.vontobel.com"` but not `"www.societegenerale.com"`?

Is there an alternative way to do this which is more structured, e.g. a dictionary that also doubles as a "list" that can be accessed by `[i]`?

---

Desired output:

```
name                    issuer_spl      issuer       website
"BEAR ESTOX X12 S"      "S"             "SEG"        "www.societegenerale.com"
"BEAR ESTOX X15 S"      "S"             "SEG"        "www.societegenerale.com"
"BULL AXP UN X3 VON"    "VON"           "Vontobel"   "www.vontobel.com"         
"BEAR AXP UN X3 VON"    "VON"           "Vontobel"   "www.vontobel.com"
```

Comment: What about creating two dictionaries, each with a different index?

Comment: What about `"Vontobel","Vontobel"`? You cannot have two of the same keys in a dict. I think you either want to use a iterable to store values for repeated keys or use a bidict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, they're "supposed" to overlap. The overlapping seems to work for "Vontobel" but not "SEG". If they're not really allowed to overlap, I guess I must create even more dictionaries to do substitution?

Comment: what output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the print statement:

```
for w in issuer:
    print(w)
    df.loc[df.issuer.str.contains(w).fillna(False), "website"] = issuer[w]
```

you may see:

```
SEG
S
SG
VON
Vontobel
```

which shows that `w` is bound to `'S'` *after* it is bound to `'SEG'`.
Since

```
In [220]: df.issuer.str.contains('SEG')
Out[220]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: issuer, dtype: bool

In [221]: df.issuer.str.contains('S')
Out[221]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: issuer, dtype: bool
```

The statement

```
df.loc[df.issuer.str.contains(w).fillna(False), "website"] = issuer[w]
```

ultimately sets the first two rows with the value `issuer['S']`, which equals
`'SEG'`, since `w` was bound to `'S'` after `'SEG'`.

Note that the order over which the keys of a dict are iterated is not specified
by the Python language; `dict` keys are not ordered. In Python3 the order may
change with each run of the program. So in Python3 your code may sometimes
"work", and sometimes not.

---

Instead, you could use `Series.map`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["BEAR ESTOX X12 S", "BEAR ESTOX X15 S", "BEAR AXP UN 3X VON", "BULL AXP UN x5 VON"], columns=["name"])

sg = {"S":"SEG", "SG":"SEG", "SEG":"www.societegenerale.com"}
vontobel = {"VON":"Vontobel","Vontobel":"www.vontobel.com"}

issuer = sg.copy()
issuer.update(vontobel) #Combine both to one dictionary

#Split last word in string to new column
df["issuer_spl"] = df.name.str.split().str.get(-1)

df['issuer'] = df['issuer_spl'].map(issuer)
df['website'] = df['issuer'].map(issuer)

print(df)
```

yields

```
                 name issuer_spl    issuer                  website
0    BEAR ESTOX X12 S          S       SEG  www.societegenerale.com
1    BEAR ESTOX X15 S          S       SEG  www.societegenerale.com
2  BEAR AXP UN 3X VON        VON  Vontobel         www.vontobel.com
3  BULL AXP UN x5 VON        VON  Vontobel         www.vontobel.com
```

provided the values in `issuer_spl` are keys in `issuer`. Note that this requires strict equality, whereas `df.issuer_spl.str.contains(w)` matches if `w` is a substring of a value in `issuer_spl`.

---

Alternatively, if you can define a rule to distinguish
which value in the `sg`, `vontobel` dicts represents the website, then you could process the dicts into two separate data structures, `issuer` and `website`. 
For example, if a website value always starts with `www` or ends with `.com`, then
you could use

```
issuer = dict()
website = dict()
for dct in [sg, vontobel]:
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if val.startswith('www') or val.endswith('.com'):
            website[key] = val
        else:
            issuer[key] = val
```

to separate the `issuer` data from the `website` data.

```
In [291]: issuer
Out[291]: {'S': 'SEG', 'SG': 'SEG', 'VON': 'Vontobel'}

In [292]: website
Out[292]: {'SEG': 'www.societegenerale.com', 'Vontobel': 'www.vontobel.com'}
```

Then you could build the desired DataFrame without relying on exact key matches:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["BEAR ESTOX X12 S", "BEAR ESTOX X15 S", "BEAR AXP UN 3X VON", 
                   "BULL AXP UN x5 VON", "BEAR DAX X3 SG 2"], columns=["name"])

sg = {"S":"SEG", "SG":"SEG", "SEG":"www.societegenerale.com"}
vontobel = {"VON":"Vontobel","Vontobel":"www.vontobel.com"}

issuer = dict()
website = dict()
for dct in [sg, vontobel]:
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if val.startswith('www') or val.endswith('.com'):
            website[key] = val
        else:
            issuer[key] = val

df["issuer_spl"] = df.name.str.extract(r'(\S+\s+\S+)$')

for i in issuer:
    df.loc[df.issuer_spl.str.contains(i), "issuer"] = issuer[i]

df['website'] = df['issuer'].map(website)
print(df)
```

yields

```
                 name issuer_spl    issuer                  website
0    BEAR ESTOX X12 S      X12 S       SEG  www.societegenerale.com
1    BEAR ESTOX X15 S      X15 S       SEG  www.societegenerale.com
2  BEAR AXP UN 3X VON     3X VON  Vontobel         www.vontobel.com
3  BULL AXP UN x5 VON     x5 VON  Vontobel         www.vontobel.com
4    BEAR DAX X3 SG 2       SG 2       SEG  www.societegenerale.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation and practical solution. This works for me.

Comment: Can I do something to make it split and keep the two last words? Something like `.str.get(-2:)`

Comment: You could use `df['name'].str.extract(r'(\S+\s+\S+)$')` or (the less efficient) `df['name'].str.split().str[-2:].str.join(' ')`.

Comment: I've added a second suggestion which would allow you use `str.contains` instead of demanding exact key matches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also solve it by this way:

Instead of using df.issuer.str.contains, using df.issuer.str.endswith.

```
for w in issuer:
     df.loc[df.issuer.str.endswith(w).fillna(False), "website"] = issuer[w]
```